# Django translation i18n thread

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have the following problem regarding translation using the i18n.
My application have the foolowing structure:

```
apps\
  app1\
  app2\
  ...
  app_n\
manage.py 
settings.py
```

And two langs: lang1 (default), and lang2.
In the app2 I have the following code that activate a language:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate, get_language
...
activate(lang2)
```

Then, in code from the app1 when I invoke

```
get_language()
```

I get the default language (lang1)
What I'm doing wrong?
May be it's because of i18n scope is one thread?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [documentation for translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language).

activate() works only for the current view. To hold it for the entire session you need to set the session variable (or a cookie if you are not using session)

```
from django.utils import translation
user_language = 'fr'
translation.activate(user_language)
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
```